# Zend Framework dom problem

Tags: html, zend-framework, dom

I want to get website shortcut icon(favicon) and stylesheet path with zend_dom query

```
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($html); 
$stylesheet = $dom->query('link[rel="stylesheet"]');
$shortcut = $dom->query('link[rel="shortcut icon"]');
```

Stylesheet query is work but shortcut icon query not work. How i do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Zend's css style query implementation. In Zend/Dom/Query.php, the query function calls a conversion function to convert the query into proper xpath format:

```
public function query($query)
{
    $xpathQuery = Zend_Dom_Query_Css2Xpath::transform($query);
    return $this->queryXpath($xpathQuery, $query);
}
```

However within the `transform()` method, they seem to be using some pretty basic regex to split up the string by spaces:

```
$segments = preg_split('/\s+/', $path);
```

Which basically means your `link[rel="shortcut icon"]` query now becomes two queries: `link[rel="shortcut` and `icon"]`

To get around this, you can use the method `Zend_Dom_Query::queryXpath()` and provide it with a proper xPath query. Like this:

```
$dom->queryXpath('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]');
```